# Centrally placing collectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have managed to place cell centrally in my app but i want to display a small portion of next cell like[image]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 1.1
        let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 10
        let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
        let padding = collectionView.bounds.width - itemWidth
        let width = itemWidth - padding
        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: itemHeight)

}
```

i want first cell have to be in the center and a small portion of next cell have to be visible. While scrolling to next cell both first and third cells small portion have to be visible with second cell in the center

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let padding: CGFloat = 10

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: padding, left: padding * 2, bottom: padding, right: padding * 2)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width - padding * 4,
                  height: collectionView.bounds.height - padding * 2)
}
```